# Regex Comma or Comma Space or Space

Tags: .net, regex

My problem is the [,\s|,|\s] will match ", " as "," and leave a extra space

So I do not get a match "Sat, Mon" with:

```
(Thu|Fri|Sat)[,\s|,|\s](Mon|Tue)
```

By matching on (Thu|Fri|Sat)[,\s|,|\s] 
I get a match on "Sat, " but the match.Value is on "Sat," (no space)

Basically I want to also get a match on "Sat,Mon" "Sat, Mon" "Sat Mon" but not "SatMon"

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(Thu|Fri|Sat)[,\s]\s*(Mon|Tue)
```

This will allow comma or space and any additional space before `Mon` or `Tue`

Your version was conflating the notions of character classes and alternation. Alternation, where you separate options with `|` must be inside of parentheses. We can make these parentheses non-capturing using the `(?: )` syntax.

Above, I used a character class. To use alternation:

```
(Thu|Fri|Sat)(?:,|\s)\s*(Mon|Tue)
```

I have used `\s` to denote whitespace, but for your purposes you could replace them with a literal space.

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes to accept but that appears to have done the trick thanks.  Regx and LINQ are two technologies I wish I knew better.

Comment: @Blam I added back some detail for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following
`\s?[, ]\s?`

Answer (score 2):

To build on @Jay answer. I would simply use a greedy match.

```
(Thu|Fri|Sat)(?:,|\s)+(Mon|Tue)
```